# Updating a local dependency in Clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen

My current project is split up in multiple sub-projects using [lein-sub](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-sub). The core sub-project depends on other sub-projects. Right now, I'm typically working through the repl and simply re-compiling the current namespace to get an updated result; However, whenever I update a sub-project, and try to re-compile that namespace, I don't get the updated results for those projects. I've tried to delete everything in `target/` and re-installing the dependencies, but nothing is working.

**How would I be able to reload sub-projects in the quickest way possible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lein-sub` doesn't put your subprojects on the classpath; if they're available at all, I expect that's due to a `lein sub install` issued at some point?

For the type of simultaneous interactive development you're asking about you can use Leiningen's built-in checkouts feature. Just create a directory called `checkouts` in the root of your top-level project and in there create symbolic links to the root directories of the dependencies. You still need to add them as `:dependencies` to `project.clj`, but the fresh code from the checkouts will be used. You can then run your REPL in the top-level project while simultaneously working on all of them, reloading the individual namespaces from the dependencies just like you would with those from the top-level project.

See [the tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md) (link to the version on master) for a detailed description.